# Why won't Wordpress custom code appear where and when I expect it?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

First, this is what I'm trying to do - add code directly before `</head>` and `</body>` in my Wordpress site.  The code must be at that exact location.  I don't want to use another plugin to accomplish it though.

I'm using a child theme as I understand the structure of child themes and how they're supposed to work.

This is what I've tried:

1. Used `add_action( 'wp_head', function )` and `add_action( 'wp_footer', function )`.  The code does get added but doesn't appear where I expect i.e. there is other code inserted after mine and before the closing tags.
2. Taken `footer.php` and `header.php` from the parent theme, added them to my child theme and then added the code snippets.  The code in `footer.php` does not get inserted at all.  The code in `header.php` does get inserted but there is other code inserted between mine and the `</body>` tag.

I need my snippets directly before the `</head>` and `</body>` tags, but can't seem to make them appear exactly where I want.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely another script is running after yours doing the same thing.

If you can't figure out what plugin or script this causes by looking at the inserted code, I'd do a project wide search on "wp_head" and "wp_footer" to find out where and when this gets fired exactly.

Not much else we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "priority" attr in `add_action( 'wp_head()', function(), 99999 )` ?
Increase the priority number, until your function is executed last.

Comment: Nope I hadn't tried that, but just did and it didn't seem to change anything.  That's a good thing to know for the future though, thanks!